What is the mistake in this shell script using if block?
I am writing a bash script and I wrote a if clause to check the existence of multiple files. The clause I used is -
if [[ -f /home/step/certs/root_ca.crt && -f /home/step/certs/intermediate_ca.crt && -f /home/step/secrets/root_ca_key && -f /home/step/secrets/intermediate_ca_key && -f /home/step/config/ca.json && -f /home/step/config/defaults.json]]; then
    echo 'Existing Certificate Authority found!\nUsing the existing certificate authority...'

It is giving this error -
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'

I tried removing the ; and got another syntax error -
syntax error in conditional expression
What is the correct syntax for checking if multiple files exist?

Does this answer your question? Why should there be spaces around '[' and ']' in Bash?

The error is at /home/step/config/defaults.json]];.
You have to rewrite it as  /home/step/config/defaults.json ]];. You missed the mandatory space before the ]].
